# Ошибка:java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name

Tags: java, servlet, properties

Структура папок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ConfigurationManager:

```
  public class ConfigurationManager {
   private final static ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.config");
   private ConfigurationManager() { }
   public static String getProperty(String key) {
    return resourceBundle.getString(key);
  }
 }
```

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не находит config.properties. Что неправильно?

config.properties:

```
 path.page.index=/index.jsp 
 path.page.login=/jsp/login.jsp
 path.page.main=/jsp/main.jsp 
 path.page.error=/jsp/error.jsp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто `ResourceBundle.getBundle("config")`.

Comment: Ошибка ушла, но теперь так и остается на этой странице - не переходит никуда.